# How to open a file with a variable extension in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have to made a vba for open a CSV from excel the problem is the files has a format:

**constan_name_file . YYY**

For **example**

file1.124514 (Day 1)

file1.144521 (Day 2)

file1.152132 (Another day)

The name file is a constan but the YYY is variable, but the file inside is a CSV. thats possible to open it?

Comment: Use Wild Cards in `DIR` to open the file. Give it a try and if you get stuck simply post the code that you tried and we will take it from there

Comment: Wild Cards I am gonna check it ! thansk!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the use of Wildcards, finally I get the code.

```
sub GetFiles(direc As String, fich As String) 

    Dim strFileName As Variant

    strFileName = dir(direc & "\" & fich & ".******")

       If Len(strFileName) > 0 Then
        'open
       end if

End sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had a problem to keep the formatting when opening a csv-file in Excel 2007. Looked around in excel-forums only to find one possible solution. Change file-extension from csv to txt.

### Tried to make a Function as general as possible. Here it is:

```
Option Explicit

Function ChangeFileExt(filnamn As String, extensionOld, extensionNew)         
Dim oldname, newname as string     

oldname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & filnamn & "." & extensionOld

newname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & filnamn & "." & extensionNew         
Name oldname As newname  

End Function

'...............................................................................

Sub change_extension()     

' Objective: Want to keep csv-format at workbook.open

' Rename file from filename.csv to filename.txt      
' Open txt-file            
' process data          
' Rename back to csv-file if neccesary        


Dim csv, txt As String           

csv = "csv"      
txt = "txt"         

Call ChangeFileExt("file_name_to_change", csv, txt)      '  omit extension in file_name_to_change         

...all kinds of code       

Call ChangeFileName("file_name_to_change", txt, csv)      '  change filename back to original name


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you forcefully open it as a CSV file

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=name, Format:=2
```

Here the 2 specifies that the file is comma delimited
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx

Comment: But name =" Full path + name File " its open a file like file1.xlsx or file2.csv the problem is my extension is the time the server made the files and its a variable number

Comment: right... best thing to do will be to go through each file in the folder (with folder object), get the file and split its name->remove the extention and add your own extention to it.
So if a file name was called file214.21Jan13 then use the "dot" as a delimiter and rename the file to file214.csv. Then use normal open to open it with vba.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, try the below code:

```
dim sFileName as string
dim sExtension as string

sExtension="YYY"
sfilename=constan_name_file & "." & sExtension

workbooks.open sfilename, Format:=2
```

Comment: The YYY changes every day file1.114525 next day file1.145245 another day file.45145

Comment: so that's how you would assign the*sExtension* variable.... for example, you could pass in the extension to use, or, as Siddharth Rout suggests, use DIR function with wildcards to get the names of the files

Comment: but I never going to know What is gonna be that variable value-

Comment: ok,. you need to use *FileSystemObject* to get the names of all the files using wildcards, then you can open the correct one.